# VS 2019 не видит установленный .net core 3.1

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Не видит имеющийся 3.1.102 и ставит 3.1.101 рядом в C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk 
Удаляю 3.1.101 через visual studio installer и теперь вообще в проектах ничего нельзя создать. Сама же система видит неткор, консольные команды работают, путь прописан в system path. Так бы и оставался на Visual Studio Code, но прохожу курс по c# и там надо делать оконные приложения в Windows Form. Я пытался найти где в VS настройки путей к компиляторам, но так и не нашел, — они вообще есть?

Comment: `dotnet --list-sdks` выводи нужную версию и путь?

Comment: и разница между 3.1.101 и 3.1.102 только багфиксы, т.е. вы могли и на 3.1.101 работать

Comment: да, я уже проверял ранее, -- выводит. Мог бы, только зачем мне плодить сущности и забивать жесткий копиями дотнета?

Comment: Потом ещё OmniSharp в Visual Code ругался зачем-то на первую строку в csproj файла <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> что-то ему не нравился Microsoft.NET.Sdk уже не помню почему. Проблема решилась полным удалением Visual Studio. Как быть дальше хз, ведь установка студии даёт две проблемы. Первую еще можно решить удалением установленного ранее netcore sdk, а вторую...

Comment: Может быть есть возможность собирать/создавать проекты Windows Forms без студии? А то мне с этим делом на 4 гига связываться ну совсем не хочется.

Comment: сейчас вроде последнии версии установщика (с оф сайта) 3.0+ удаляют все промежуточные версии, например ставя 102, он удалит 101, 100 и т.д

Comment: Мой установочный фаил студии вчерашней давности.